# Use a variable or function in MYSQLs ALTER TABLE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

In Mysql/MariaDB I like to set the comment of an existing column to a string containing the current date.

But I only get SQL syntax errors. I've tried so far:

```
SELECT @date := CONCAT('saved at', now());
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY 
    column_name <complete column definition> COMMENT @date;
```

Also not working:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY
    column_name <complete column definition> COMMENT now();
```

Of course this works:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY
    column_name <complete column definition> COMMENT 'saved at today';
```

Is this possible without an external script?

Comment: Comment is a literal, not an expression. Prepared statement may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @sql := CONCAT ( 'ALTER TABLE {table_name} ',
                     'MODIFY {column_name} {complete column definition} ',
                     'COMMENT \'saved at ' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '\'' );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6deb7043cfbef3879cd8c289c479c85)

Comment: Thanks, that works. The link to the MYSQL documentation could be useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html